# new String(bytes) causing "Maximum call stack size exceeded" in GWT client

Tags: java, gwt

The following works fine for short strings

```
result = new String(bytes);
```

I have a byte[] that's approximately 140000 bytes and when I try to create a `String` from it using the above code the browser throws the exception `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. I'm using Using GWT 2.6.0.

I believe this exception can be thrown when large arrays are created, but I can't find an alternative way to create a string from a byte[] in GWT. Are there any suggestions or workaround I can use to get this working?

The JavaScript exception and call stack are below.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
valueOf_86  @   String.java:630
utf8ToString    @   String.java:210
_String_0   @   String.java:322
_String_1   @   String.java:237
handleHttpResponse_7    @   BaseRequest.java:38
onResponseReceived  @   GwtNet.java:56
$fireOnResponseReceived @   Request.java:315
onReadyStateChange_1    @   RequestBuilder.java:42
(anonymous function)    @   XMLHttpRequest.java:402
apply_24    @   Impl.java:58
entry0  @   Impl.java:385
(anonymous function)    @   Impl.java:91
```

Comment: Which version of GWT you are using ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ GWT 2.6.0. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: 2.6 is pretty old - there was a very similar bug (also to do with arrays, but rooted in the arraylist impl with a pre-allocated size) that was fixed in 2.7 or later - have you tried a version from within the last year or so?

Comment: @ColinAlworth Unfortunately I'm tied to the version used by LibGDX, which is 2.6 for now.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't work out an easy way around this, so I ended up writing a method to chop the UTF-8 byte array into chunks and decode it chunk by chunk. If anyone knows a better way then please post a new answer.

```
/**
 * Decoding very long strings in GWT causes exceptions, so anything that could be decoding a large string in
 * GWT must use this method instead
 * @param bytes The array of UTF-8 bytes
 * @return String representation of the array
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
 */
public static String getUTF8String(byte[] bytes) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int charLength;
    int lastDecodeOffset = 0;
    int charCount = 0;

    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length) {
        if ((bytes[offset] & 0b10000000) == 0b00000000) charLength = 1;
        else if ((bytes[offset] & 0b11100000) == 0b11000000) charLength = 2;
        else if ((bytes[offset] & 0b11110000) == 0b11100000) charLength = 3;
        else if ((bytes[offset] & 0b11111000) == 0b11110000) charLength = 4;
        else if ((bytes[offset] & 0b11111100) == 0b11111000) charLength = 5;
        else if ((bytes[offset] & 0b11111110) == 0b11111100) charLength = 6;
        else throw new UnsupportedEncodingException("Invalid UTF-8 data");

        if (offset + charLength > bytes.length) {
            throw new UnsupportedEncodingException("Invalid UTF-8 data");
        }

        offset += charLength;
        charCount++;

        if (charCount > 2048 || offset >= bytes.length) {
            stringBuilder.append(new String(bytes, lastDecodeOffset, offset - lastDecodeOffset, "UTF-8"));
            lastDecodeOffset = offset;
            charCount = 0;
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```